# Does pointwise convergence to a continuous function on a closed interval imply uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let's suppose that $(f_n)_{n}$ is a sequence of continuous functions that converges pointwise to a continuous function $f(x)$ on a **closed** interval $[a, b]$. Is then the convergence uniform, too?

If it is so, how do you prove it? If it isn't, could you give a counterexample, please?

---

### My attempt

I managed to write down the **hypothesis** in symbolical terms, but could not go beyond that:

- continuity of the sequence  ($x_0\in[a, b]$):

$\forall n, \ \forall \epsilon >0 \ \ \exists \delta>0 \  : \ |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\epsilon $

- continuity of the limit function ($x_0\in[a, b]$):

$\forall \epsilon >0 \ \ \exists \delta>0 \  : \ |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon $

- pointwise convergence:

$\forall x\in[a, b], \ \forall \epsilon >0 \ \ \exists n_\epsilon>0 \  : \ n\geq n_\epsilon \Rightarrow |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon $

The **thesis** should be:

$\forall \epsilon >0 \ \ \exists n_\epsilon>0 \  : \ n\geq n_\epsilon \Rightarrow |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon \ \ \forall x\in[a, b]$

---

### Note

Please do not bring sequences such as that of $x^n (x\geq 0)$ as a counterexample, because they are **not** counterexamples:

$\text{for  } n \rightarrow \infty , \ x^n \rightarrow f(x)= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if  } 0 \leq x<1 \cr
1 & \text{if  } x=1
\end{cases}$

so there is a pointwise convergence to $f(x)$ on $[0, 1]$; but $f(x)$ - the limit function - is *not* continuous, then this example lacks the conditions for the theorem to be applied.

Comment: If the main point is to request feedback on your own proof attempt, you should use the ([tag:proof-verification]) tag, see the [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-verification/info).

Comment: I've added the [tag:proof-verification] tag to your question.  Please remove it if you feel that this was inappropriate.  There are a number of possibly related questions: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/785997), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1023917), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/309141).

Comment: @XanderHenderson The above post does not contain any proof to be verified.

Comment: @Adayah Then this question offers nothing new which has not already been addressed on MSE before, and should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

Check out $f_n(x) = nx e^{-nx}$ on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: I am sorry but in this case the function $f(x)$ to which $f_n(x)$ pointwisely converges in $[0, 1]$ is not continuous, so the theorem cannot be applied: $ f(x)= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if  } 0 \leq x<1 \cr
e^{-1} & \text{if  } x=1
\end{cases} $

Comment: @MattiaPegolo: $f(1)=0$ not $e^{-1}$.

Comment: @MattiaPegolo . If $x>0$ then $e^{nx}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(nx)^j/j!>(nx)^2/2!.$... An analogous example:  Suppose $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,1/3n]\cup [1/n,1]$  but $f_n(2/3n)=n.$ Then for any $x\in [0,1]$ the set $\{n\in \Bbb N: f_n(x)\ne 0\}$ is finite.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I am sorry, I meant $f(x)= \begin{cases} e^{-1} & \text{if  } x=0 \cr 0 & \text{if  } 0<x \leq 1 \end{cases} \ $ ; but even with this correction I think that I was wrong.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam ...I was wrong, because $f(x)=0$ in $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 6):

Another example is $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
n^2x&0\le x\le\frac{1}{n},\\
2n-n^2x&\frac{1}{n}\le x\le\frac{2}{n},\\
0&\frac{2}{n}\le x\le 1
\end{cases}
$$
The graph looks like a triangle of height $n$ and base $2/n$ so the $\int_0^1f_n(x)\mathrm{dx}=1.$  If the convergence were uniform, the integrals would go to $0$.

Answer (score 5):

As Adayah's counterexample shows, this does not work without extra hypotheses. However, if the pointwise convergence is monotone, then a [classical theorem of Dini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) shows the convergence is indeed uniform.

Comment: But with the extra hypothesis required by the theorem above and only with those ones (no monotony needed), can it work?

Comment: @MattiaPegolo: no it doesn't because Adayah's counterexample proves it.

Comment: I think Dini's theorem requires that the functions themselves be monotone increasing.  I know the Wikipedia article doesn't list this as a hypothesis, but it is used in the proof given there.

Comment: @saulspatz: No. Dini's theorem also works on compact spaces where the functions themselves being monotone doesn't even make sense. See these notes by my colleague Joel Feldman: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/dini.pdf

Comment: I guess I remember the theorem wrong, or rather, I must be confusing it with another theorem.  I can remember (from 40-odd years ago) a theorem with $4$ hypotheses: compactness, monotonicity, pointwise covergence, and monotone convergence, and examples showing they were all necessary.  I've alway thought it was Dini's theorem, but I see it can't have been.  This is going to drive me crazy!

Comment: @saulspatz: when I learned that stuff 30 some years ago, I remember there were two theorems of Dini: one as above and if my recollection is correct another one about monotone functions converging pointwise but with no monotonicity hypothesis on this pointwise convergence. I think that also gives uniform convergence because if you control a sufficiently tight finite grid you also control what happens between grid points.

Comment: Indeed, in the French system https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8mes_de_Dini this is known as Dini's 2nd theorem, although it seems to be due to Polya.

Comment: Obviously, it's the second theorem I was thinking of.  You have helped preserve an old man's sanity :-)

Answer (score 1):

It might help to think of the negation of uniform convergence. Given a sequence $f_n$ and a limit function $f$, $f_n$ does *not* converge uniformly to $f$ if there is an $\epsilon$ such that for all $N$, there exist $k$ and $x_k$ such that $k>N$ and $|f_k(x_k)-f(x)|>\epsilon$. That is, to disprove uniform convergence, it suffices to find an infinite sequence of pairs $(n,x_n)$ such that $f_k(x_k)$ does not go to zero. An example would be $f(x) = 0$, $x_k = 2^{-k}$ with $f_k$ chosen such that $f_k(x_k)$ is equal to a constant. To make this converge pointwise to $f$, it suffices that each $x$ has nonzero $f_k(x)$ for only finitely many $k$. Or, we can make it even simpler and have only one such $k$ for each $x$. This can be done by having $f_k$ be zero for all but an interval of length $10^{-k}$ centered at $x_k$. It is then simple to construct continuous functions that satisfy these conditions.

BTW, "converges pointwise" is more standard than "pointwisely converges", and "attempt" rather than "trial".